# Was wird in diesem Sketch auf Bairisch gesagt?

Tags: bavarian

In dem Sketch ["Klick Klick Hurra: Deutschlands Klickfabrik"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmSwyZal7WY) von "Gute Arbeit Originals" geht es um eine Alm in Berchtesgaden auf der "biologische Klicks für YouTube" produziert werden. Die Hauptperson spricht dabei mit einem deutlichen (wahrscheinlich) bairischen Dialekt.

Der komplette Sketch ist untertitelt, wie auch bei realen Dokus, wenn eine Person Mundart redet. Ab [Minute 2:40](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmSwyZal7WY&t=2m40s) gibt der Untertitler allerdings auf und fügt Fragezeichen ein. Die ersten Wörter und Sätze ("Saupreiß kommt hier auf meinen Hof gelaufen") kann ich noch nachvollziehen. Was sagt er allerdings ab Minute 3:02? Insbesondere die Stelle an der als Untertitel nur noch "Ich verstehe kein Wort. Sorry Leute." steht? Mir geht es da nämlich genauso ^^.

Nicht ausschließen will ich, dass dies bairisch klingender Nonsens ist. Schließlich ist das immer noch Comedy.

Comment: Das was fehlt ist "schleich di" und "Saupreiß". Ab "Sorry Leute" habe ich auch null Ahnung. Könnte nachfragen.

Comment: "Finanzler" könnte sich auf [den österreichischen Ausdruck für "Finanzbeamter"](https://www.ostarrichi.org/wort/11948) (den es vielleicht auch im Bayerischen gibt?) beziehen. Der Satz würde dann etwas bedeuten wie "Da kommt so ein Typ von Auswärts, so ein Fuzzi vom Amt, auf _meinen_ Hof und will mir Vorschriften machen." Beim nächsten Satz vermute ich ebenfalls, dass er bewusst unverständlich ist. Die Bedeutung dürfte entweder in Richtung "Da hat der sich aber geschnitten" oder "Dem hab ich aber Bescheid gestoßen" gehen.

Comment: In den Kommentaren stand "A Packerl Watschn is glei afgrissn" -> "N Paeckchen Ohrfeigen ist gleich aufgerissen". Finde ich passend.

Comment: Wobei "Schleich di" soviel heißt wie "Schleich Dich davon", wörtlich übersetzt, oder "Hau ab/Verschwinde!"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Boarische Mitschrift

ca. 0:47

> So, seawas, gö, griaß eich. So, kummt's eni.
> So, jå, serwas, gö. Des's a Sauweda gö? So, megts es a Bia?

ca. 1:00

> Jå. - Jå, då wern die Klicks gmacht, gö, des is ois natürlich.
> So, då drüm is da Klickstoi, und für die Shares fåhrn mia in Summa auf'd Oim aufi, gö? Jå.

ca. 1:16

> Nåjå, gö, des woa scho oiwai die Vogler-Oim, gö? na?
> Jå, mein Foda hot Klicks gmocht, gö, jå, i moch Klicks und mei Bua, der wiad a wida Klicks mocha, gö, jå. So is de hoid, gö.
> Gö, jå, es is ois ökologisch, des is nix chemisch's oder so, gö.
> Jå, na, des muaß scho g'scheit gmocht sein damit des wos taugt. Gö? Jå.
> Des is a hundat Prozent noch am Reinheitsgebot, gö ja. Und da lås i ma a nix sågn. So, gö?

ca. 1:50

> Jå, kimmts jetzt?

ca. 1:59

> Jå, då måch ma die Retweets für Twitter, gö.
> Jå, bis so a Lieferung fertig is, jå guat, des dauat hoit a bissl, gö.
> Des hod ma hoit im Gfui<sup>1</sup>, des måch ma wia die Maurer.
> Jå, na, kimmt's na, auf geht's!

ca. 2:24

> Jå, na, des is da Klickstoi, gö, so. Na, des muaß ma scho von Hånd måcha<sup>1</sup>, gö, sunst is des nix. So, jå.
> Jå, mia måcha a die Buidl<sup>1</sup> für di Videos, gö?

ca. 2:44

> Du, geh, Bursche, geh, glei fångst du ane. Glei fång...
> Geh, jetzt, geh schleich di, du Grattler. Komm, schleich di.
> Saupreiss, kummt da auf mein Hof glaffa!
> I glaub i spinn!
> Måch zua jez!
> Då kimmt so a Saupreiss-Finanzler auf mein Hof und wü ma wos fazein, gö?
> Du, gö, a Packl Watschn<sup>2</sup> is glei aufgrissn gö?
> Aah. Saupreiss.

---

### Hochdeitsche Iwasetzung

ca. 0:47

> So, servus, nicht wahr, grüß' euch. So, kommt herein.
> So, ja, servus, nicht wahr. Das ist ein Sauwetter<sup>3</sup> nicht wahr? So, mögt ihr ein Bier?

ca. 1:00

> Ja. - Ja, hier werden die Klicks gemacht, nicht wahr, das ist alles natürlich.
> So, da drüben ist der Klickstall, und für die Shares fahren wir im Sommer auf die Alm hinauf, nicht wahr? Ja.

ca. 1:16

> Naja, nicht wahr, das war schon immer die Vogler-Alm, nicht wahr? Na?
> Ja, mein Vater hat Klicks gemacht, nicht wahr, ja, ich mache Klicks und mein Sohn, der wird auch wieder Klicks machen, nicht wahr, ja. So ist das eben, nicht wahr.
> Nicht wahr, ja, das ist alles ökologisch, das ist nichts chemisches oder so, nicht wahr.
> Ja, nun, das muss schon gut gemacht sein, damit das gut ist. Nicht wahr? Ja.
> Das ist zu hundert Prozent nach dem Reinheitsgebot<sup>4</sup>, nicht wahr, und da lasse ich mir auch nichts sagen. So, nicht wahr?

ca. 1:50

> Ja, kommt ihr jetzt?

ca. 1:59

> Ja, hier machen wir die Retweets für Twitter, nicht wahr?
> Ja, bis so eine Lieferung fertig ist, ja gut, das dauert eben<sup>5</sup> ein bisschen, nicht wahr.
> Das hat man eben<sup>5</sup> im Gefühl, nicht wahr, das machen wir wie die Maurer.<sup>6</sup>
> Ja, nun, hopp auf, los geht's<sup>7</sup>!

ca. 2:24

> Ja, nun, das ist der Klickstall, nicht wahr, so. Nein, das muss man schon von Hand machen, nicht wahr, sonst ist das nichts. So, ja.
> Ja, wir machen auch die Bilder für die Videos, nicht wahr?

ca. 2:44

> Du, geh, Bursche, geh, gleich fängst du eine<sup>8</sup>, Gleich fäng...
> Geh, jetzt, geh verzieh dich, du Grattler<sup>9</sup>. Komm, verzieh dich.
> Sau-Preuße<sup>10</sup>, kommt hier auf meinen Hof gelaufen!
> Ich glaube, ich bin verrückt<sup>11</sup>!
> Mach zu jetzt!
> Da kommt so ein sau-preußischer<sup>10</sup> Finanzbeamter<sup>12</sup> auf meinen Hof und will mir etwas erzählen, nicht wahr?
> Du, nicht wahr, eine Packung Ohrfeigen ist schnell aufgerissen, nicht wahr?<sup>13</sup>
> Aah. Sau-Preuße.<sup>10</sup>

---

### Åumeakungan

1. Typisch für die in Bayern gesprochenen bairischen Dialekte ist der Diphthong *»ui«* wie in *»Gfui«* und *»Buidl«* (in Österreich: *»Gfüh«* und *»Büdl«*) oder die Endung *»-a«* bei infiniten Verben wie *»måcha«*, die in Österreich und auch Standartddeutsch und auf *»-n«* enden (*»måchn«* bzw. *»machen«*).
2. Leider stark genuschelt und sehr schwer verständlich. Dem Kontext nach handelt es sich um eine Gewaltandrohung, daher erscheint mir das »Packl Watschn« am plausibelsten zu sein.
3. Das Präfix »Sau-« wird vor allem in Bayern gerne verwendet, um die Abwertung des damit versehenen Begriffs zum Ausdruck zu bringen. Ein »Sauwetter« ist daher »schlechtes Wetter«. Die vorangestellte Sau findet man auch in Österreich und sogar auch in Gegenden in denen keine bairischen Dialekte gesprochen werden, aber deutlich weniger häufig als in Bayern.
4. Eigentlich: »Das ist zu 100% nach dem Reinheitsgebot **gemacht**«.
5. Wörtlich: »halt«, im Sinn von »eben« oder »nun mal«
6. Maurern sagt man nach, dass sie gelegentlich nicht nach genauem Maß arbeiten, sondern Mauern manchmal nach persönlichem Empfinden aufstellen.
7. Wörtlich »kommt nur, auf geht's«, eine freundliche Aufforderung tätig zu werden.
8. »Gleich fängst du eine« ist eine Androhung einer Ohrfeige.
9. ursprünglich waren Grattler Tiroler, die Handkarren gezogen haben. Heute: verarmtes Pack, bzw. allgemein abwertendes Schimpfwort. Von »Kratten« = zweirädriger Handkarren (verwandt mit »Krattn, Kraxn« = Korb, den man wie einen Rucksack auf dem Rücken getragen hat)
10. Zum Präfix »Sau-« siehe oben (3). Aus Sicht der Bayern sind alle Menschen, die zwar Deutsch, aber nicht Bairisch sprechen, *Preißn*. Die Bezeichnung stammt zwar von den *Preußen* ab, meint aber alle deutsch sprechenden Nicht-Bairischsprecher. (Österreicher sind zwar auch keine Bayern, sprechen aber bairische Dialekte und gehören daher nicht zu den Saupreissn.) In Österreich ist der Begriff *Saupreiss* nicht in Verwendung. Stattdessen wird hier der Begriff *Piefkes* für genau dieselbe Bevölkerungsgruppe verwendet, die in Bayern als *Saupreissn* gelten.
11. Im Sinn von: »Das kann doch nicht wahr sein.«
12. Allgemeines Schema: XY-Beamter oder -Angestellter = XYler. Beispiele: Jemand, der bei der Post angestellt ist: Postler. Finanzbeamter = Finanzler. Allgemein (vor allem in Österreich): Jemand der schwer arbeitet (»ana, der schwa hacklt«) = Hackler (vergleiche: [Hacklerregelung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacklerregelung))
13. Wortspiel aus »eine Packung aufreißen« = »eine Packung öffnen« und »Ohrfeigen aufreißen« = »Schläge ins Gesicht bekommen«.

Comment: Besonders charmant finde ich die Überschriften ^^. Eine ähnliche Redewendung zu den Maurern ist übrigens "Es halten wie ein Dachdecker". Was auffällig ist sind die vielen "gö/nicht wahr". Sind die auch in der Alltagssprache so verbreitet? Wobei das eigentlich schon eine eigene Frage wert wäre ^^.

Comment: Zu "gö/nicht wahr": Das hängt extrem stark vom jeweiligen Sprecher ab. Ich unterrichte an einer Fachhochschule (theoretische Informatik sowie Statistik), und da müssen die Studenten auch ihre Arbeiten vor den Studienkollegen präsentieren. Und da gibt es welche, die sprechen fließend und frei, während bei einigen der Vortrag hauptsächlich aus "äh", "ah" und ähnlichen einsilbigen Verlegenheitslauten besteht. Einige sagen auch sehr oft "oder" oder "ja". Das bayrische "gö" fügt sich nahtlos in diese semantisch sinnfreien Verlegenheitslaute. Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOK8uAaAmQU

Comment: Solche Vorträge kennen wir alle ^^. Mindestens noch aus der Schule oder Uni. Wobei "gö/nicht wahr" mE hier allerdings eher eine Interjektion als ein Verzögerungs/-Verlegenheitslaut ist. Etwas weiter nördlich kenne ich das "gö" als "ne" und finde es bei inflationärem Gebrauch extrem nervig.

Comment: "gö" heißt immer noch "gelt". Meine Müchner Großmutter brachte dieses schöne Wort in  (gefühlt) jedem zweiten Satz unter.  Der Hesse sagt "gell", im Ruhrgebiet heißt es "woll" und im südlichen Teil Westfalens ganz vornehm "wohl". Eine Sprachgrenze zuim Rheinland tut sich auf, indem das "woll" durch "ne " ersetzt wird. Und damit lasse ich den Kommentar mal gut sein, wa.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Das stimmt zwar, die von dir genannten Wörter gehören aber zur Umgangssprache oder zu Dialekten und sind nicht Bestandteil des Standarddeutschen, also jener Sprache, in die ich den Dialekt-Text übersetzt habe. Wenn ein Schüler in seinen Aufsatz eine der von dir genannten Interjektionen einbringt, wird das vom Lehrer als Fehler angestrichen. Und außer in wörtlichen Zitaten von umgangssprachlichen Äußerungen wirst du diese Wörter auch nicht im Büchern und Zeitungen finden, und du wirst sie auch nie aus dem Mund von Berufssprechern (z.B. Nachrichtensprecher) hören.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Natürlich sind diese schönen Wörtchen keine Bestandteile des Standarddeutschen und schon gar nicht des Schriftdeutschen. Mir ging es auch nur darum, dass "gö" für "gelt" steht - und das ist salonfähiger als "gö". Vgl. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gelt_ja_oder_wirklich und https://www.duden.de/synonyme/gelt_ja_oder_wirklich sowie https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gelt .